# Acceptable values for variables in rational expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Determine the non-permissible values of $5a^2+80a/(50ab^2$)

I know how to determine the non-permissible values of an equation, but this is the only question that I've encounter that contains two variables; both a and b.

Would I solve for a, and disregard b or solve for them both?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean $5a^2 + 80a / (50 ab^2)$?  (BTW this is a term, not an equation) The only thing you should avoid is division by zero. Can you see what $a$ and $b$ values would cause this?

Comment: For $ab \neq 0$, $5a^2 + 80a / (50 ab^2)=5a^2 + \dfrac8{5b^2} >0$ isn't it?

Comment: As others have suggested, you want to consider $50ab^2 = 0.$ As for what to do because this contains two variables, think about why $(x-1)(x+2) = 0$ leads to $x-1=0$ or $x+2=0$ and, and then ask yourself whether the principle used can also be used in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that makes it non-permissible is having the denominator zero, so what values of $a,b$ make $50ab^2$ zero?  The trap is to avoid canceling $a$ before answering the question.  $0/0$ is still unacceptable.